# How to return a dynamic range based on a horizontal lookup on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup

I've been trying to get a range of data based on a date criteria to be found horizontally, but I can't wrap my head around getting the columns referenced in a formula and return adjacent columns and rows.

For example:
If the criteria is 01/06/2021 in a certain cell, then it should return columns H through K and the rows below up to the totals.

[image]

Appreciate any time/help!

Comment: Can't really understand your criteria, mind to show some desired output based on the range?

Comment: Hello@KinSiang I'll be looking for the data for a certain day. each day has a couple of columns with data I'm interested in. In the example above, if the date criteria is 01/06/2021, then columns H through K are to be returned.
I'm not sure if this would be a filter, an index+match, or a hlookup function to return such data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one formula where you may want to use to filter your data,

```
=query({A:H},"Select " &"Col"&match(K5,$A$1:$H$1,0)-2&", Col"&match(K5,$A$1:$H$1,0)-1&", Col"&match(K5,$A$1:$H$1,0)&", Col"&match(K5,$A$1:$H$1,0)+1)
```

Where the following formula is mean to find the position of the date you want to search for (For explanation). The reason to use it is to reach the `query` selection such as `Col5, Col6` etc:

```
match(K5,$A$1:$H$1,0)
```

Here is the result based on date in `K5`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, too bad cannot be `arrayformula` inside to shorten the formula :)